# Understanding JavaScript code for counting occurrences of each character in a string

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I need some help understanding the following code:

```
function AllChars(str) {

var myObj = {};
for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
if(myObj[str[i]]===undefined){
  myObj[str[i]]=0;
}
myObj[str[i]]++;

}
return myObj;

}

AllChars('banana');

Output
{b: 1, a: 3, n: 2}
```

It basically returns an object where each key is a character in the given string. Here is the question:

The for loop runs from 0 to the length of the string.  Then the if function checks str[0] which is the first element should be the letter 'b' then this letter 'b' is added to the myObj[str[i]]] this is what I don't understand  why would myObj[str[0]] be undefined when it was 'b' in str[0]?

Comment: it is checking whether `b` is already available as a key in dictionary `myObj`

Comment: Because when you have duplicate letters then the first time a letter is encountered the property doesn't exist and you create it....but after that it already exists for the duplicates and you don't want to reset it to zero each time

Comment: *"why would myObj[str[0]] be undefined when it was 'b' in str[0]? "* `str[0]` is not undefined but `myObj[str[0]]` (or, `myObj['b']`) is initially undefined until a value is assigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. The `AllChars` function

Your function takes a string as parameter and loops through the string (`str`)... And for each loop, it retrieves the next character in the string.

1. Now, if the character have not yet been encountered before, it is
   added to the "empty" object as a key, of which value is `0`. This way, it create a counter of occurrences of that character in the string `str`.
2. Otherwise (if it (that character: `str[i]`) has already been
   encountered), needless to index it again in `myObj`.

At the end of each loop, the counter (of the current character) is incremented.

At the end of the function, `myObj` is returned.

## 2. `AllChars('banana');`

This line call the function `AllChars` defined above with  the string `'banana'` as parameter.

## 3. The output

The output suggest to me that the code is being ran from a javascript console, which output the value of `myObj` returned from `AllChars('banana');`

It is either the browser console or the node.js console.

So the output is representative of that (key => value) object.

```
{b: 1, a: 3, n: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

myObj is a new empty object. So what the is being checked is if we started counting that letter yet, if no it initializes it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The code counts how many times each letter appears in the given string.
If there was no letter like this yet it adds a letter as a property and after increase it's count.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you try to get something from an object that isn't there it will return 'undefined'. The code above simply utilizes that feature as a means of checking weather or not that letter from the 'str' parameter is present in the myObj object.

Answer (score 0):

Count occurrence of each char in string . ES6 solution is more elegant  :

```
const chars = string =>
  [...string].reduce(
    (all, e) => ({ ...all, [e]: !all[e] ? 1 : all[e] + 1 }),
    {}
  );
```

```js
const chars = string =>
  [...string].reduce(
    (all, e) => ({ ...all, [e]: !all[e] ? 1 : all[e] + 1 }),
    {}
  );

console.log(
  chars('bananaa')
)
```